# Tastypie with SessionAuthentication error on:return getattr(request.user, username_field)

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using SessionAuthentication with Tastypie and receiving the following error. This error does not show up when I run the app locally, only when I deploy the application using uWSGI.

> {"error_message": "getattr(): attribute name must be string",
>   "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File
>   \"/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 201,
>   in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n 
>   File \"/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line
>   432, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request,
>   **kwargs)\n\n  File \" /venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 460,
>   in dispatch\n    self.throttle_check(request)\n\n  File
>   \"/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 557,
>   in throttle_check\n    identifier =
>   self._meta.authentication.get_identifier(request)\n\n  File
>   \"/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/authentication.py\", line
>   283, in get_identifier\n    return getattr(request.user,
>   username_field)\n\nTypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be
>   string\n"}

uWSGI ini looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = x.x.x.x:x
chdir = /project/
pythonpath = /venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
env= DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.production_settings
module = project.wsgi
processes = 8
threads = 2
buffer-size=32768
master = True
protocol = uwsgi
logto = /project/uwsgi_error.log
```

This problem also seemed to crop up when I added some related resources to the API. In particular, I'm importing a model from another app as a foreign key. Conceptually it's something like this:

```
class Employee(BaseModel):
    employee = models.ForeignKeyField('store.Store')
```

Then in the api.py

```
import models
from store import models as store_models

class StoreResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = store_models.Store.objects.all()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()

class EmployeeResource(ModelResource):
    store = fields.ForeignKey(StoreResource, 'store', full=True)
    class Meta:
       queryset = models.Employee.objects.all()
       authentication = SessionAuthentication()
```

Comment: It's most likely your Django version is different on deploy environment or somehow user Model isn't ready yet: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/compat.py

Comment: I'm running Django 1.6.2 locally and on the deploy using a virtual environment. I'll look into the User model.